# Need VBA assistance copying data to a row in sheet 2 based on value in sheet 1 and remove orignial data from sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively inexperienced in VBA code, but have a workbook that I am trying to organize based on "Status" of items listed in rows.

I have a drop down box in column "M" that allows the user to select "HOLD" or "RELEASED"... Based on this value, the line item needs to be copied and pasted into the same exact row in sheet 2 if the value = "RELEASED" (Example of line item range is ("B7:N7")(Sheets are formatted exactly the same). I have code for this, but I need to remove the line item that is "RELEASED" from sheet 1 after it is copied and pasted into sheet 2.

Here is what I have... (Parts Staging Log = Sheet 1 ... Released Parts Log = Sheet 2)

```
Public Sub CopyPasteRows()

Sheets("Parts Staging Log").Select
' Find the last row of data
FinalRow = Range("B828").End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through each row
For x = 7 To FinalRow
' Decide to copy based on column M value "RELEASED"
ThisValue = Range("M" & x).Value
If ThisValue = "RELEASED" Then
Range("B" & x & ":BM" & x).Copy
Sheets("Released Parts Log").Select
NextRow = Range("B828").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("B" & NextRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Parts Staging Log").Select
End If
Next x

End Sub
```

If anyone can assist me with a deletion of the original line item that would be wonderful. Other comments are accepted as well!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on this: remove the loop (too slow) and replace with autofilter

```
Public Sub CopyPasteRows()
Dim FinalRow As Long

With Sheets("Parts Staging Log")
' Find the last row of data
    FinalRow = .Range("B828").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B6:BM" & FinalRow).AutoFilter
    .Range("B6:BM" & FinalRow).AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:="RELEASED"
    .Range("B7:BM" & FinalRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Released Parts Log").Range("B828").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .Range("B7:BM" & FinalRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .Range("B6:BM" & FinalRow).AutoFilter    
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, it works great! I do have one question.... How can I make this "update" using this code when the workbook is opened. There will be multiple people accessing this from a network folder, and they will mark line items "RELEASED" when they open the workbook. When they close it and re-open it later to "release" or add more items can the sheets be updated and the information be copied then. I don't want the line item to be deleted from sheet 1 as soon as they select "RELEASED" in column M..... Thanks so much for the response!!!!

Comment: I could assign the macro to a button I suppose that runs the code if clicked on. The button could be titled "RELEASE PARTS" or something along those lines.... Thanks again, good call on eliminating the loop!

Comment: You can also put that macro in the workbook_beforeSave event of the workbook module. This will run it every time somebody saves the file. Putting it on a button works too.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, sorry.... I close the question how? I provided feeback but cannot locate any "Close Question" type action? Again, thanks for the help it was spot on!

Comment: There should be an checkmark button. Check out the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask